# How to list items inside One Drive folders with python O365 library

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

Im trying to list the items inside folders using O365 library with client credentials (with own identity). I have set up permissions for File read and write in Azure and am able to get results if I use the auth flow on behalf of user.

**Auth flow(works - but requires interaction):**

```
from O365 import Account

credentials = (client,secret)
account = Account(credentials)
storage = account.storage()

if account.authenticate(scopes=['onedrive_all',('offline_access')]): #Once u get the token file with refresh token u can remove the if statement to avoid always asking user input
    print('Authenticated!')
    
my_drive = storage.get_default_drive() 
root_folder = my_drive.get_root_folder()

# iterate over the first 25 items on the root folder
for item in root_folder.get_items(limit=25):
    if item.is_folder:
        print(list(item.get_items(2))) # print the first two element on this folder.
```

**Credentials flow - With app's own identity (doesnt need user interaction but doesnt work):**

```
from O365 import Account

credentials = (client,secret)
account = Account(credentials, auth_flow_type='credentials', tenant_id=tenant)
storage = account.storage()

if account.authenticate():
    print('Authenticated!')
    
my_drive = storage.get_default_drive() 
root_folder = my_drive.get_root_folder()

# iterate over the first 25 items on the root folder
for item in root_folder.get_items(limit=25):
    if item.is_folder:
        print(list(item.get_items(2))) # print the first two element on this folder.
```

How can I get the client credentials method working? Currently I get an empty list, and also errors on other functions that work with the first technique

Answer (score 1):

Solved the credentials flow by using

```
account = Account(credentials,auth_flow_type='credentials',
tenant_id=tenant,main_resource=myemail)
```